# How to run doctest examples from a string, but not a docstring? Why is indentation needed?

Tags: python, doctest

According to the documentation of Python's `doctest` module, the function [`run_docstring_examples`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#doctest.run_docstring_examples) can be called with various objects, such as a function, class, or module, but also a string.

I assumed that when called with a string, it would run the examples in that string.
But this does not seem to work.
Here is what I tried:

```py
example = """
>>> True
False
"""

import doctest
doctest.run_docstring_examples(example, globals(), verbose=True, name="example")
```

This results in `Finding tests in example` only; nothing more.

What am I doing wrong?

Playing a bit more, and changing how `example` is defined into (note the indentation)

```py
example = """
    >>> True
    False
"""
```

it does work, and the output is as expected:

```
Finding tests in example
Trying:
    False
Expecting:
    True
**********************************************************************
Line 2, in example
Failed example:
    False
Expected:
    True
Got:
    False
```

So, now the question is:

- Why is indentation needed?
- Is that a bug or a feature?

**Edit**:

- Environment: Python 3.7.2 from within a Jupyter notebook, with IPython 7.2.0
- Directly in Python 3.7.2 interpreter it does work as expected.

Comment: I think this a feature because a docstring "is a string literal that occurs as the first statement in a module, function, class, or method definition." https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. What version of Python are you using? How are you running the code? I'm using Python 3.6.9, calling directly from the shell. See [mre] for advice.

Comment: @Vorsprung No, `doctest` is supposed to be able to test arbitrary strings, not just docstrings.

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.2 from within a Jupyter notebook, with IPython 7.2.0. When I run it directly in the Python 3.7.2 interpreter, it does indeed work as expected. Strange.